# when click the button, execute func with 2 arguments, but i can not reach "event" inside the func

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const handleClickTextChange = (eng, tr, e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);-----> here is bug.
    if (getFirstChildElement.innerText == `${tr}`) {
      getFirstChildElement.innerText = `${eng}`;
    } else {
      getFirstChildElement.innerText = `${tr}`;
    }
    getParentElement.classList.toggle(styles.container_single_card_changing);
};
```

```
<div
    onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnterDetailButton}
    onMouseLeave={handleOnMouseLeaveDetailButton}
    onClick={() =>
        handleClickTextChange(item.turkishWord, item.englishWord)
    }
    className={styles.container_single_card}
    key={index}
></div>
```

I tried that execute different properties like onMouseEnter,onMouseLeave, and onClick. But it didn't give me what I want, so I have to fix it.

Comment: You're only passing two arguments to `handleClickTextChange()`; you'd need to pass the event as well to access it from within the function.

Comment: Change it to `onClick={e => handleClickTextChange(item.turkishWord, item.englishWord, e) }`. You need to get the event parameter and pass it on to your function. Also you really shouldn't be using something like `.innerText` when you use React. Use the descriptive syntax JSX gives you.

Comment: @Mushroomator appreciate